# jQuery .each css is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an jQuery object with 3 members:

```
var elements = $("#" + this.wrapperName + ">ul>li>a>img");
Object { 0: <img>, 1: <img>, 2: <img>, length: 3, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → JSUmstellung, selector: "#newsdesk>ul>li>a>img" }
```

I want to change eachs CSS-Property, so I made this:

```
elements.each(function(index, element) {
    element.css({
        "width": elemWidth,
        "height": elemHeight,
        "top": elemTop,
        "left": elemLeft
    });
}
```

When I run this code, I just get the following error:

> TypeError: element.css is not a function

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to access my element in another way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're not going to use `index` or `element`, you don't have to include them: `elements.each(function() {`. Then use `$(this)` in the function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `element` is a DOM node, without access to jQuery methods, what you need to use is `$(this)` or `$(element)`:

```
elements.each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).css({
        "width": elemWidth,
        "height": elemHeight,
        "top": elemTop,
        "left": elemLeft
    });
}
```

Or:

```
elements.each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).css({
        "width": elemWidth,
        "height": elemHeight,
        "top": elemTop,
        "left": elemLeft
    });
}
```

Or you could, instead, use `cssText` (if you *really* want to work with DOM nodes):

```
elements.each(function(index, element) {
    element.style.cssText = 'width: ' + elemWidth + '; height: ' + elemHeight + ' top: ' + elemTop + '; left: ' + elemLeft;
}
```

Bear in mind that, within `each(function (index, element){ ... });` `element` is exactly the same as `this` (and, as a corollary, `$(this)` is the same as `$(element)`). I'm not sure quite what the benefit is, of using the `element` at all.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks, I thought jQuery did that automatically.. :D

Comment: A jQuery object is just a wrapping around the underlying DOM element. That wrapper comes with some overhead, though. To support the effort of being as fast as possible, jQuery rarely (never?) automatically wraps a DOM object. So the base DOM objects are the context (`this`) and what get passed in (`element`).

Comment: Re: advantage of using `element` - maybe if instead of using an anonymous function, you're calling an existing function that's in a different context. So using `this` in that context would not represent the DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap it in the jquery format. Like so:

```
elements.each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).css({
        "width": elemWidth,
        "height": elemHeight,
        "top": elemTop,
        "left": elemLeft
    });
}
```

notice the:
`$(element)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $(this) selector inside the each loop

```
elements.each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).css({
        "width": elemWidth,
        "height": elemHeight,
        "top": elemTop,
        "left": elemLeft
    });
}
```